# Material-UI withStyles not applying background color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I used withStyles to apply a background linear gradient (within the `container` object in `styles`) and that worked fine, but I followed the same format to create another object in `styles` named `child` to apply a background color to the  child component of , but nothing happened. Why wasn't a background color applied?

```
import { Grid } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const styles = {
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: '100vh',
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #aa6775 30%, #984355 90%)' // Works
  },

  child: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow' // Does nothing
  }
};

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid
        id="quote-box"
        className={this.props.classes.container}
        justify="center"
        container
      >
        <Grid xs={11} lg={8} className={this.props.classes.child} item>
          .....
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a project with Create React App and ran your code and it appears to be working fine.  Perhaps you are running an older version of Material?

For reference here are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1"
  },
```

[image: MaterialUIExample]

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. I'm using the same versions. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Did you check to see if there is another `child` style somewhere else in your document that is overriding it?  I would also check the inspector to see what styling is being applied.

Comment: Oh yeah, that must be it. The component passed into the Grid item component is wrapped with a Material-UI Card component.